# Understanding Const Pointer to Pointer in Newt Widget Kit

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I am getting this error, which requires me to pass a **const char****  instead of just **char****:

```
client.c:34:33: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘newtEntry’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  fld_email=newtEntry(16,1,"",20,&email_buf,NEWT_FLAG_SCROLL);
                                 ^
In file included from client.c:4:0:
/usr/include/newt.h:249:15: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 newtComponent newtEntry(int left, int top, const char * initialValue, int width,
```

The calling function is defined like this:

```
newtComponent newtEntry(int left, int top, const char * initialValue, int width,
            const char ** resultPtr, int flags) {
....
}
```

My question is, why does newtEntry() function requires pointer to pointer to char if inside it , it allocates new array with malloc() and it actually writes in it the data that the user has entered. This is very misleading, the content referenced by pointers DOES NOT remain constant! Obviously, when compiling I get the warning. What is the correct way to compile this code? I do not want to violate the 'const' rules, I want to compile correctly.

For there reference, I will put my code, and the code of the function itself that belongs to Newt library.

My code using Newt library:

```
err_code_t read_account_data(void) {
    #define WINDOW_WIDTH    40
    #define WINDOW_HEIGHT   10
    char *email_buf,*password_buf;
    int width,height;
    int ret;
    newtComponent form,fld_email,fld_password,lbl_email,lbl_password;

    newtGetScreenSize(&width,&height);
    if ((width<WINDOW_WIDTH) || (height<WINDOW_HEIGHT)) {
        return(ERR_SCREEN_SIZE_TOO_SMALL);
    }
    ret=newtCenteredWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT,"Account data");
    if (ret) {
        return ERR_SYS_ERROR;
    }
    form=newtForm(NULL,NULL,0);
    lbl_email=newtLabel(1,1,"Email:");
    fld_email=newtEntry(16,1,"",20,&email_buf,NEWT_FLAG_SCROLL);
    lbl_password=newtLabel(1,3,"Password:");
    fld_password=newtEntry(16,3,"",20,&password_buf,NEWT_FLAG_SCROLL|NEWT_FLAG_RETURNEXIT|NEWT_FLAG_PASSWORD);
    newtFormAddComponents(form,lbl_email,fld_email,lbl_password,fld_password,NULL);
    newtRunForm(form);

    newtPopWindow();
    return ERR_NO_ERROR;
    #undef WINDOW_WIDTH
    #undef WINDOW_HEIGHT
}
```

The code of the newtEntry() function inside the source code of Newt library available at Fedora's repository:

```
newtComponent newtEntry(int left, int top, const char * initialValue, int width,
            const char ** resultPtr, int flags) {
    newtComponent co;
    struct entry * en;

    co = malloc(sizeof(*co));
    en = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    co->data = en;

    co->top = top;
    co->left = left;
    co->height = 1;
    co->width = width;
    co->isMapped = 0;
    co->callback = NULL;
    co->destroyCallback = NULL;

    co->ops = &entryOps;

    en->flags = flags;
    en->cursorPosition = 0;
    en->firstChar = 0;
    en->bufUsed = 0;
    en->bufAlloced = width + 1;
    en->filter = NULL;

    if (!(en->flags & NEWT_FLAG_DISABLED))
    co->takesFocus = 1;
    else
    co->takesFocus = 0;

    if (initialValue && strlen(initialValue) > (unsigned int)width) {
    en->bufAlloced = strlen(initialValue) + 1;
    }
    en->buf = malloc(en->bufAlloced);
    en->resultPtr = resultPtr;
    if (en->resultPtr) *en->resultPtr = en->buf;

    memset(en->buf, 0, en->bufAlloced);
    if (initialValue) {
    strcpy(en->buf, initialValue);
    en->bufUsed = strlen(initialValue);
    en->cursorPosition = en->bufUsed;

    /* move cursor back if entry is full */
    if (en->cursorPosition && !(en->flags & NEWT_FLAG_SCROLL ||
            wstrlen(en->buf, -1) < co->width))
        en->cursorPosition = previous_char(en->buf, en->cursorPosition);
    } else {
    *en->buf = '\0';
    en->bufUsed = 0;
    en->cursorPosition = 0;
    }

    en->cs = NEWT_COLORSET_ENTRY;
    en->csDisabled = NEWT_COLORSET_DISENTRY;

    return co;
}
```

Struct entry:

```
struct entry {
    int flags;
    char * buf;
    const char ** resultPtr;
    int bufAlloced;
    int bufUsed;        /* amount of the buffer that's been used */
    int cursorPosition;     /* cursor *in the string* on on screen */
    int firstChar;  /* first character position being shown */
    newtEntryFilter filter;
    void * filterData;
    int cs;
    int csDisabled;
};
```

Comment: @alk Yes it does compile. You can download the full source code at this url: fedorahosted.org/newt , I have added the definition of the struct , it is declared at the beginning of entry.c file of Newt sources

Answer (score 1):

`const char** resultPtr` means the following:

- You **cannot** assign values to `**resultPtr`.
- You **can** assign values of type `char*` to `*resultPtr`.
- You **can** assign values of type `char**` to `resultPtr`.

This means the following:

- `malloc` **can** write a memory address to `*resultPtr`.
- You **cannot** modify the chars in `(*resultPtr)[i]` for any index *i*.

If you wish to modify the value stored in `(*resultPtr)[i]` for an index *i*, you can do the following:

```
char** anotherPtr;
anotherPtr = (char**)resultPtr;
```

Then you **can** modify the characters in `(*anotherPtr)[i]` for any index *i* (under the precondition that the memory segment corresponding to variable `(*anotherPtr)[i]` is allocated).

Comment: the last part of "anotherPtr" does not work. I get this error after this code "email=email_buf;
    email[3]='*';
    printf("modified email: %s\n",email);" : warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type

Comment: If I understand correctly, Newt widget kit does not allow to modify user entered values by any chance. The only way I can do it is to copy the data, to another memory location, is that correct?

Comment: The reason for `resultPtr` being delared as `const` in `newtEntry` function may be because resultPtr is also referenced in the return value `co` (`co->data->resultPtr = resultPtr`). So if you overwrite `**resultPtr`, it will have a side effect on `co`. And such side effects may be undesired, so it is safer to declare `resultPtr` as `const`. An option is to copy the data to another `char`-array. Another option is to simply ignore the warning – a warning is not an error! Maybe you can even deactivate the warning with a `#pragma` precompiler option.